# How to make jar file from command prompt

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I have been trying making jar file for my `gradle` project but always found error 
`could not find or load main class CalculatorServer`

My `compile (.class)` files are in the following path in windows file system
`D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\CalculatorGRPC\build\classes\main\com\grpc\calculator`

When i trying to create jar file for Main class e.g `CalculatorServer` using folloiwng command

`D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\CalculatorGRPC\build\classes\main\com\grpc\calculator>java -cp test.jar com.test.calc.CalculatorServer`

Following error occur
`could not find or load main class CalculatorServer`

**Edit**

Sorry I have posted wrong commands here.

My command for creating jar file is as follows

`D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\CalculatorGRPC\build\classes\main\com\grpc\calculator> echo Main-Class: CalculatorServer >manifest.txt`
`D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\CalculatorGRPC\build\classes\main\com\grpc\calculator>jar cvfm CalculatorServer.jar manifest.txt *.class`

When i run this jar file

```
`D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\CalculatorGRPC\build\classes\main\com\grpc\calculator>java -jar CalculatorServer.jar
```

Getting same error

`could not find or load main class CalculatorServer`

Comment: You aren't making jar file at all... either you got a wrong title or you pasted your command wrong. Surely there is something wrong with the posted commands, but I won't waste time pointing the solution unless you clarified what you are trying to do.

Comment: @glee8e I hv made changes .. I am quite new to java enviroment.  Struck here for quite some time now !!

Answer (score 0):

You are in the wrong directory. No matter what are you trying to do, as long as that operation involves compiled class files, you should be in the output root, which is the `XXXXX\build\classes\main` folder.

The reason for this is that java classloaders 
will try to find `/com/foo/Bar.class` in the jar if it is ordered to load class named `com.foo.Bar`. If you just pack a jar like that, the jar tool will place your classes right in the root directory of the output archive(you can confirm this by using a archive tool like 7z to investigate), which panic the classloader and gives you an error.

By the may, manifest should be named MENIFEST.MF adn placed under /META-INF directory, or same error would pop up again, if your manifest was written in a correct format.

PS: Why the heck you are doing these all by your bare fist? This is what gradle is supposed to do, or why is it called build automation? There should be your desired jar files somewhere under the `/build/` directory, typically `/build/lib/`.